# Swift: How to display string array from Firebase in TableView?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I have an array of strings(Names) in Firebase Database. I'm new in swift so I don't know how to display that array in table view. I need every name to display in single cell.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    guestList.count
   }

   
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "guestsCell", for: indexPath) as! GuestListOnTableTableViewCell
    
       var guest: GuestModel
       guest = guestList[indexPath.row]
    
       cell.guestNameLabel.text = guest.guestName!
    
           return cell
   }
```

Here is my database:

[image]

I need to look like:
in cell 0 -> Mills
in cell 1 -> William ....

Comment: Your code looks reasonable (Aside from the force-unwrap on `guest.guestName`. That's asking for a crash if `guestName` is nil.

Comment: What happens when you run this code?

Comment: @DuncanC when I run this code it displays all names (stored in another uid). I don't know how to display names from guestsOnTable array. I need how to display each name from array in each cell.

Comment: @AnDon If it's displaying names from someplace else, maybe there's a separate issue. Can you show the code where you're retrieving the data?